# Get inner array value based on condition with other values in mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a DB structure as follows:

```
{
    "Title": "AAA",
    "Photos": ["/aaa/aaa.png"],
    "Loc": "XXX",
    "Emp": "SSS",
    "Rate": [{
        "Rating": 2,
        "RateID": "12345654654",
        "RatedDate": new Date()
    }],
    "Fav": [{
        "FavValue": 2,
        "FavID": "1111",
        "FavDate": new Date()
    }]
}
```

Here, I want to fetch all the details by default. But from array, i need to get the object that matches the ID.

In "Rate" array it needs to match "RateID" and in "Fav" array it need to match "FavID".

**Both "Rate" and "Fav" wont contains objects always.**

I have tried foll mongoose aggregate:

```
ss.aggregate([
        { $unwind: "$Rate" },
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": '$_id',
                "Title": { "$first": "$Title" },
                "Loc": { "$first": "$Loc" },
                "Emp": { "$first": "$Emp" },
                "Photos": { "$first": "$Photos" },
                "Rate":  { $max: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$Rate.RateID", new ObjectId(id) ] }, '$Rate.Rating', null ] } },

                "Fav":  { $max: { $cond : [ { $eq : [{ "$size": "$Fav" }, 0]}, null, { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$Fav.FavID", new ObjectId(id) ] }, '$Fav.FavValue', null ] } ]} }
            }
        }
    ], function (err, AvgResult) {
        res.json({"result": AvgResult});
    });
```

For "Rate", if the array is empty it returns empty result as **{}**

For "Fav", it returns null always if the array is empty or if it contains object

If I send the ID as '12345654654', the result should be like

```
{
    "Title": "AAA",
    "Photos": ["/aaa/aaa.png"],
    "Loc": "XXX",
    "Emp": "SSS",
    "Rate": 2,
    "Fav": null
}
```

If the ID is "1111", the result should be

```
{
    "Title": "AAA",
    "Photos": ["/aaa/aaa.png"],
    "Loc": "XXX",
    "Emp": "SSS",
    "Rate": null,
    "Fav": 2
}
```

If "Fav" is empty array in DB like "Fav": [] and ID - is "12345654654", then the result should be as follows

```
{
    "Title": "AAA",
    "Photos": ["/aaa/aaa.png"],
    "Loc": "XXX",
    "Emp": "SSS",
    "Rate": 2,
    "Fav": null
}
```

can any one help to get the expected result in all the above scenario..

Comment: Your example isn't the best. Are you saying that you want to return **"all"** "Rate" array entries but somehow "highlight" the entry or entries that are present in "Fav", if any? Would that not be self evident by the content in "Fav" already? It's not really clear what the expected results would be. Perhaps more source document examples and the expected results might explain your case more clearly.

Comment: Please see the edit above for the expected result in different scenario..

Comment: So what you are saying is you just want to supply an "ID" value and then have this return the "Value" from whichever array contains the item that matches? Correct? You need to understand in this case that not only are these seperate fields but the "ID" and "Value" fields are named completely differently. There are no "wildcard" searches for field names in MongoDB, and as such this means JavaScript evaluation on the server. That's bad. You would be a lot better off with a single array, consistent field names, and just an identifier for each for "rate/fav".

Comment: Yes.. I need to get the result that matches the ID. The issue here is when i dont use unwind (so that I can check the empty array), the value is returning 'null' even if the ID matches